# Windows 8 boot into UEFI firmware settings missing

Tags: windows-8, boot, uefi

On a homebrew computer I've installed a Intel DX79SR Mainboard, changed the BIOS mode to UEFI and installed Windows 8.

I further switched UEFI to fast booting, which works nicely.

Now I wanted to boot into the UEFI firmware settings from Windows 8, but the option to do so is missing from the advanced boot options. Instead of the 6 advanced Options as described in [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/b8/designing-for-pcs-that-boot-faster-than-ever-before) I only see 5. The UEFI Option is missing.

Luckily the mainboard itself has a rescue option, but I wonder how I get Windows 8 to recognize my UEFI bios? Shouldn't it be possible to boot into the UEFI settings from Windows itself?

Answer (score 5):

If you installed Windows 8 the U/EFI way you should be able to access UEFI options.

To check if you boot UEFI way - when in Windows run on admin command prompt:

**bcdedit**

output lists bootmgr and loader/s.

for example:

```
    Windows Boot Loader
 =========================

identifier              {current}
device                  partition=C:
path                    \Windows\system32\winload.efi
description             Windows 8
```

If path ends in **.efi** - you boot U/EFI way

else path ends in **.exe** - you boot BIOS way.

---

To install Windows 8 the UEFI way you have to boot installation media (USB/DVD) the UEFI way.

UEFI firmware usually allows BIOS booting (over CSM) **and** UEFI booting for DVD/USB.

Destination disk for installation must be a GPT style disk.

When converting a MBR disk to GPT disk (usually) existing partitions are lost.

Comment: Mine had .efi bit still the UEFI option is missing as described in the question